# Debugging Resque Jobs With RubyMine without Rails

Tags: ruby, redis, resque, rubymine, activesupport

Using Rubymine, and I'm trying to debug some ruby scripts that generate jobs in redis via resque.

- Not using Rails
- I am using active support

The issue is I have no idea and can't google up any anything really useful directly on the this subject.

I'm not against trying something else like pry but I would love to be able to just debug these jobs from Rubymine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, it is a practice to push logic into a class/object, write automated tests, do a sanity manual testing, so that you don't have to run into these kind of issues. All your job has to do is just call the well tested method.

Comment: Yes of course but if you inherit a big ball of mud it would  be nice if you could debug the code so you can refactor it.

Comment: I feel you man! Maybe there is an option on resque that allows you to convert async jobs into sync calls and use pry/rubymine debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to debug in Rubymine by launching the Rake task.  Go to `Run -> Edit Configurations... -> + (Top right button) -> Rake` and setup it up with:

- Task name: `resque:work`
- Environment variables: `QUEUE=*`

Save the configuration and launch it from `Run -> Debug...`